# Fetch data from database on checkbox using Angular

Tags: javascript, mysql, angular

I'm trying to get data from the database(MariaDB) and if it exists checkbox must be checked.
For example, I will give you screenshots on my application:
 [Here I input some data and send it on(by submit button) database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX8kC.png)

In the database, I have two tables.
First is "reasons".In "`reasons`" table in column "name" I save the data from the input box.

```
    **table "reasons"**
    id   |   name
    -------------
    1    |   reason1
    4    |   reason2
    5    |   reason3
    6    |   reason4
    7    |   reason 5
    ..   |   ......
```

The second table is "reason_to_transaction".Here "`reason_id`" is reference to "`id`" from table "`reasons`" i.e. every "reason name" have a "`transaction_type`"(which can be more than one, for example, id=4 from "`reasons`" table has two "`transaction_type`"-sell,buy.

```
    **table "reason_to_transaction"*
 reason_id |   transaction_type
    ----------------
      1    |   sell
      4    |   sell
      4    |   buy
      5    |   sell
      5    |   buy
      5    |   pko
      6    |   sell
      7    |   sell
       ..  |   ......
```

When I open menu"reasons"(on bulgarian: "основание") i got this view:
[Menu reasons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zoUB.png)
When I click on some of those names I got this view(edit mode):
[Edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga0MV.png)

In the input box, I've got the activeItem.id on which I clicked. Below this input box has checkboxes which I want to be checked.
This is my problem. I don't know how to get data from these two tables from the database and check checkbox which is a need.
I have this code:

This is my controller where I'm creating an array of checkboxes:

```
app.controller("ReasonCtrl", function($rootScope, $scope){
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.editMode = false;
    $scope.activeItem = false;
    $scope.albums = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'sell'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'buy'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'pko'
      },
      {
        id:4,
        name: 'rko'
      }
      ];
```

With this function, I've got the data from activeItem:

```
$scope.editItem = function(item){
        $scope.editMode = true;
        $scope.activeItem = angular.copy(item);
        $('.editMode1').show();
        $('.addMode1').hide();
        $('.myBox').hide();
        };

    $scope.createItem = function(item){
        $scope.editItem({});
    };

    $scope.saveItem = function(){
        console.log($scope.activeItem);
        //delete $scope.activeItem.hash_method
        var objectToSave = {

            name: $scope.activeItem.name,
            id: $scope.activeItem.id
        };

        if($scope.activeItem.id){
            defaultAdapter.query('UPDATE reasons SET name = :name WHERE id =:id ',
              { replacements: objectToSave, type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE }
            ).then(defaultAdapter.query('SELECT rt.transaction_type,rt.reasons_id FROM reason_to_transaction rt INNER JOIN ',{type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE}))
            .then(projects => {
              console.log(projects);
              $scope.editMode = false;
                $scope.activeItem = false;
                $scope.refresh();
            });
        } else {
            defaultAdapter.query('INSERT INTO reasons SET name = :name',
              { replacements: objectToSave, type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE }
            ).then(projects => {
              console.log(projects);
              $scope.editMode = false;
                $scope.activeItem = false;
                $scope.refresh();
            });

        }

    };
```

I'm still learning to programme and i don't have an idea how to get this data and check these checkboxes...
Could someone help me?
I'm using Angular(sequelize method) and MariaDB
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to query your database directly from the browser. You can't do that.  If it was possible, anybody would be able to do anything with your database... Life expectancy of your data : a few hours if you're lucky :) You have to make a call to your server, which will query the database in a secure way then send the results back to the client.

Comment: I'm doing this with Sequelize method. "defaultAdapter.query()..." Or maybe i don't understand your answer?

Comment: What is sequelize? What is defaultAdapter?

Comment: @JeremyThille Sequelize is a promise-based Node.js ORM for Postgres, MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite and Microsoft SQL Server. It features solid transaction support, relations, eager and lazy loading, read replication and more. defaultAdapter is just the variable

Comment: Node.js, yes. Not Angular. It is meant to be used on a server, not from a browser.

Comment: Ok on the server. But what is mean this?

Comment: Hmmm... how to say? You have a long way to go :) You have to learn the server-client architecture, take a few tutorials about client-server-database communication. It's way too vast for me to explain it here! Check this out : https://i.stack.imgur.com/A841z.jpg